# how to configure an external database for an application running on a cloud

Tags: cloud, war

I am a newbie in the cloud world. I am using cloud foundry to deploy my war file to a PAAS cloud. 
My application is not a spring-boot application. 
My application also connects to an external database.

I am using tomcat as a server. 
How can I deploy my war and  make the java-buildpack tomcat to understand the database configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You cant make tomcat build pack to decide any database setup.  Build pack is just a way to define the run time dependencies of your application like java tomcat etc.

To connect to a database, you need a database service. In cloud foundry every external service like database, mq, etc has to be used as service. 
U need to bind these service then to your application, and application can read these properties and make a datasource connection out of that service.

For Example 
Pivotal Web Service(run.pivotal.io - Cloud Foundry provided by Pivotal) provides a MYSQL service , called p-mysql. You can see this in cloud foundry marketplace(Marketplace is a place where the different services can be viewed on cloud foundry, cf marketplace command can be used to see this).

```
http://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/1-8/
```

This service has different plans. You can choose plan which suits your needs. Then u can create a service of p-mysql inside your cloud foundry space with a logical name like mymysqlservice.

Then inside your application manifest you can define the services that has to be binded to the application.

```
services:
   - mymysqlservice
   - myrabbitmqservice
```

If you do this and then push the app to cloud foundry, then in runtime application can find the properties of the database(like url,username,password etc) in the System environment variable called VCAP_SERVICES.

```
https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP_SERVICES
```

The datasource can be created in your application using these properties.

Spring cloud cloud foundry project under spring cloud project has useful easy methods to auto discover these services and inject datasources to spring applications.

```
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server_2
```

So inside cloud foundry every external service would be a service that has to be defined inside marketplace.

If you have your own deployment of cloud foundry then u need to define your own rdbms service inside your cloud foundry deployment which later can be used to create a service and bind to the application.